# sleep() within a user-space thread implementation

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, system, sleep

Why is it okay to use sleep() with a kernel thread implementation, but not within a user-space thread implementation? Is it because sleep has to be in system call?

Comment: why do you say you cannot sleep in user-space thread?

Comment: If you want the entire program to pause, go for it. If you want just that thread to pause.... Well... Do you know what user space threads *are* and how they differ from kernel threads?

Answer (score 1):

To begin, the user thread/kernel threat distinction is the creation of bad textbooks on operating systems.

Kernel threads are threads.

"User threads" are simulations of thread using run-time libraries.

The behavior of simulated threads is entirely system dependent. Some dreadful operating systems textbooks say that blocking calls made in simulated threads block the entire process. That may be true in some implementations but it is not true in all.